# Adaptive AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, adaptive-design

Here is our jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on("load resize", function(){
        if ($(window).width()<=960){
            $(".myDirective").css("flex-direction", "column")
        }
        else{
            $(".myDirective").css("flex-direction", "row")
        }
    })
});
```

Now I want to create an AngularJS directive with the same function. How should I do this?

I know how to create a directive with the specific style:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.css({
                flexDirection: 'column'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But how to add conditions?

Answer (score 1):

In your html apply this `windowWidth` directive to your element whose class you have set to `.myDirective`.

```
Ex. <p class="myDirective" window-width></p>


app.directive('windowWidth', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, $element) {
            scope.$watch(function() {
                if($window.width < 960) {
                    $element.css("flex-direction", "column");
                } else {
                    $element.css("flex-direction", "row");
                }
            })
        }, 
    }
});
```